# Kafka Confluent community Platform 6.2 <> ksqlDB version upgrade

Tags: apache-kafka, debian, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I am looking for a proper way to update ksqldb version from 0.17 (which is already packaged into the confluent platform as the standalone 0.17 version) to 0.19.
I use Confluent Platform 6.2 packages (community edition).

Please, have you got any ideas to achieve this ?

Thanks a lot,
Ma2.

Comment: Have you tried to use the APT repo / DEB package mentioned in the documentation? Or use Docker?

Comment: Hey @OneCricketeer, thanks for your reply.
Actually, I have been too fast to post on SO.

 Sorry for that.

I can't use Docker on my environment yet and the "APT repo / DEB packages" kept saying to me that I "already have the latest version of ksqldb" packaged with confluent platform 6.2.
So I uploaded via tarball, it worked like a charm.

Comment: Interesting that they'd use the same package name for the bundled on and the standalone installation, but I can understand that would cause naming conflicts/confusion elsewhere. Anyways, yeah, the standalone tarball works too